# PostgreSQL multiple database dml

Tags: plpgsql

I want to insert same data in `db_two.tab_emp` table automatic by trigger or anything.

```
create database db_one;
create table db_one.tab_emp(id int, name text);

create database db_two;
create table db_two.tab_emp(id int, name text);

insert into db_one.tab_emp values(101,'king');
```

Is there any possible way to insert or update foreign database table if I insert or update own database table at a time?

Comment: yes it's possible, you can use replication, or you can use a trigger that uses db_link.

Comment: can you please give me a example? @Jasen